# How do I check for a group of successive entries in a list?

Tags: python, list

I'm working through a Code Academy challenge where I'm meant to define a function that compares an email with a list of "negative words and phrases", and after two words/phrases in the list have appeared in the email, the rest of the occurrences should be censored.

This is where I'm at:

```
#Censors a list of negative words after the second appearance of a word from the list
def censor3(email):
    negative_words = [
        'concerned', 'behind', 'dangerous',
        'alarming', 'alarmed', 'out of control',
        'help', 'unhappy', 'bad',
        'upset', 'awful', 'broken',
        'damage', 'damaging', 'dismal',
        'distressed', 'distressing', 'concerning',
        'horrible', 'horribly', 'questionable',
        'danger'
    ]
    ecensored3s = re.split('(\W)', email)
    negative_count = 0
    for i in range(len(ecensored3s)):
        word = ecensored3s[i]
        if word in negative_words or word.lower() in negative_words:
            negative_count += 1
            if negative_count > 2:
                ecensored3s[i] = 'REDACTED'
    ecensored3 = "".join(ecensored3s)
    return (ecensored3)
```

This works for all single words in negative_words, but won't find phrases like 'out of control'. Is there a way I can check for a phrase within a list where every word is its own entry?

Input e-mail example:

```
Board of Investors,

Things have taken a concerning turn down in the Lab.  Helena (she has insisted on being called  Helena, we're unsure how she came to that moniker) is still 
progressing at a rapid rate. Every day we see new developments in her thought patterns, but recently those developments have been more alarming than 
exciting.

Let me give you one of the more distressing examples of this.  We had begun testing hypothetical humanitarian crises to observe how Helena determines 
best solutions. One scenario involved a famine plaguing an unresourced country.

Horribly, Helena quickly recommended a course of action involving culling more than 60% of the local population. When pressed on reasoning, she stated 
that this method would maximize "reduction in human suffering."

This dangerous line of thinking has led many of us to think that we must have taken some wrong turns when developing some of the initial learning 
algorithms. We are considering taking Helena offline for the time being before the situation can spiral out of control.

More updates soon,
Francine, Head Scientist
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of `email`?

Comment: The same reason none of the elements in the list ['out','of', 'control'] are equal to the string 'out of control'. You're comparing a list of words  (`ecensored3s`) to a list of strings that can be made of one or more words (`negative_words`)

Comment: Why split the string and iterate over it all? Why not iterate over all the negative_words and then do `email.replace(foo, 'REDACTED')`?

Comment: Not related but replace this `for i in range(len(ecensored3s)):` and this `word = ecensored3s[i]` with simply `for i, word in enumerate(ecensored3s):`.

Comment: example of email:

https://pastebin.com/U6wjyuuS

Comment: If I iterate over the negative_words instead of the email, the negative_count will go up based on the order of words in negative_words, not in order of when they appear in the email.

Comment: Why `out of control` should be replaced since you have just one occurrence of it in the sample e-mail?

Comment: it allows the first two occurrences of any entry in the list, and then all other occurrences of any entry in the list are censored.

Answer (score 1):

That was a fun exercise.

To find longer phrases than a single word, don't use `split` – you can but you'll have to jump through hoops to make it work. Use `re.findall`, so you can add word breaks before and after each phrase (to prevent it matching `bad` inside `Barbados`) and a flag to make the search case insensitive.

That will give you the list of words that occur. You can use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) to find the exact locations of all phrases, start to end. Store these in a list (I also stored the word itself for debugging – you don't need that). Then sort the list on the `start` item, discard the first two items to leave them alone, and loop through this list, replacing each `start-end` fragment with `REDACTED`. As you are changing the actual text here, this needs to be done end-to-start, because else the positions of all next phrases will be off.

```
import re, pprint

text = '''
Board of Investors,

Things have taken a concerning turn down in the Lab.  Helena (she has insisted on being called  Helena, we're unsure how she came to that moniker) is still 
progressing at a rapid rate. Every day we see new developments in her thought patterns, but recently those developments have been more alarming than 
exciting.

Let me give you one of the more distressing examples of this.  We had begun testing hypothetical humanitarian crises to observe how Helena determines 
best solutions. One scenario involved a famine plaguing an unresourced country.

Horribly, Helena quickly recommended a course of action involving culling more than 60% of the local population. When pressed on reasoning, she stated 
that this method would maximize "reduction in human suffering."

This dangerous line of thinking has led many of us to think that we must have taken some wrong turns when developing some of the initial learning 
algorithms. We are considering taking Helena offline for the time being before the situation can spiral out of control.

More updates soon,
Francine, Head Scientist
'''

negative_phrases = [
    'concerned', 'behind', 'dangerous',
    'alarming', 'alarmed', 'out of control',
    'help', 'unhappy', 'bad',
    'upset', 'awful', 'broken',
    'damage', 'damaging', 'dismal',
    'distressed', 'distressing', 'concerning',
    'horrible', 'horribly', 'questionable',
    'danger'
]

# mark occurrences of all negative phrases
occurrences = []
for phrase in negative_phrases:
    search_result = [(m.group(0),m.start(0),m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'\b'+phrase+r'\b', text, re.IGNORECASE)]
    if search_result:
        occurrences += search_result

occurrences.sort(key=lambda match: match[1])
pprint.pprint (occurrences)

# skip the first two
occurrences = occurrences[2:]

# remove the remaining phrases from the text -- this must be done in reverse!
for _,start,end in reversed(occurrences):
    text = text[:start]+'REDACTED'+text[end:]

print (text)
```

... and the result seems to be what you are looking for. The first two dangerous words, 'concerning' and 'alarming' are left and the rest gets [REDACTED]:

```
[('concerning', 42, 52),
 ('alarming', 314, 322),
 ('distressing', 372, 383),
 ('Horribly', 572, 580),
 ('dangerous', 794, 803),
 ('out of control', 1040, 1054)]

Board of Investors,

Things have taken a concerning turn down in the Lab.  Helena (she has insisted on being called  Helena, we're unsure how she came to that moniker) is still 
progressing at a rapid rate. Every day we see new developments in her thought patterns, but recently those developments have been more alarming than 
exciting.

Let me give you one of the more REDACTED examples of this.  We had begun testing hypothetical humanitarian crises to observe how Helena determines 
best solutions. One scenario involved a famine plaguing an unresourced country.

REDACTED, Helena quickly recommended a course of action involving culling more than 60% of the local population. When pressed on reasoning, she stated 
that this method would maximize "reduction in human suffering."

This REDACTED line of thinking has led many of us to think that we must have taken some wrong turns when developing some of the initial learning 
algorithms. We are considering taking Helena offline for the time being before the situation can spiral REDACTED.

More updates soon,
Francine, Head Scientist
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting and I'm starting to pour over it but would you happen to have a suggestion on how to find a phrase in a split list instead? Your method is clearly superior and with fewer "hoops", but I'd like to keep my answer as close as I can to using methods I've already learned.

Your code has enough methods that I've never seen that I'd just be aping your answer.

Comment: @JonathanM: if you want to keep using `split`, consider replacing the spaces in "out of control" (and other multiword Danger Words) with another symbol. Both in your list and in the text itself. Then split will keep them together, and you can compare them with your list.